# Listview item not deleting

Tags: android

in my application i add name, address and phone no of person, when i click on view button it will show name, address and phone no. in listview, in my list view each record contain one check box in front of them, if in my list view there are 15 records, out of them only 10 are visible on list view, when i check the 15th record and press delete button it will give me null pointer exception on check box, means the non visible items in the listview are not deleting from list when i check them and press delete, following is my code,

```
for(int i = 0;i<simpleCursorAdapter.getCount();i++){
            View view = listData.getChildAt(i);
            CheckBox deleteSelectes = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkDelete);

            if(deleteSelectes.isChecked()){
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int delete_id = cursor.getInt(0);
                myDbhelper.deleteSelected(delete_id);
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListTableData.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;i<simpleCursorAdapter.getCount();i++
```

This doesn't prevent i from increamenting to 15. So the `listData.getChildAt(i);` is actually saying `listData.getChildAt(15);` which is *Null*. Try with **i-1**.

Comment: done this but still getting the same problem, i think check box view is not getting for the last item,

Comment: Did you try deleting from the top 10. And see if that works first.